# How to run sqldatasource1 by dropdownlist selectedindex ==0 and sqldatasource2 by dropdownlist selectedindex ==1

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have asp.net page . I have 2 stored procedure to search city and to search country. I use 2 SqlDataSource. the SqlDataSource1 for search city and the SqlDataSource2 for search country.my problem is that I want use dropdownlist1 for select type of search.when selected index is 0 the SqlDataSource1 be run. and when
selected index is 1 the SqlDataSource2 be run.my code on click button event:

GridView1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
               GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: PLease show some code.

Comment: Without a better problem description all I can recommend it to use an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use one `SqlDataSource` and change its `SelectCommnad` according to the selection of `dropdown`.

```
if(dropdwon.SelectedValue == "0"){
  SqlDataSource1.SelectCommnad = "Your sp to search city";
  GridView1.DataSourceID = SqlDataSource1;
  GridView1.DataBind();
}
else if(dropdwon.SelectedValue == "1"){
  SqlDataSource1.SelectCommnad = "Your sp to search country";
  GridView1.DataSourceID = SqlDataSource1;
  GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is setup 2 SQLDataSources and do:

```
if (ddl.SelectedIndex == 0) {
   GridView1.DataSourceID = sqlDS1.ID;
}
else {
   GridView1.DataSourceID = sqlDS2.ID;
}
GridView1.DataBind();
```

By switching the ID of the data source control and rebinding, that effectively does what you want.